# Difference in boxing between PTS and UD?

Tags: scoring, boxing

What's the actual difference? Isn't the UD (Unanimous Decision) a "united" decision, where all the referees agree who is the winner? What's then the meaning of PTS?

Answer (score 1):

PTS means a result on points, where a UD statement would be inappropriate. For example,

- historic fights may not have the judge's scores available in record, and therefore it is unsure whether a UD is what occurred
- a number of regions had only one person deciding points in their history, and UD implies more than one person
- any other situation where a decision on points was made but where there is not enough information to say it was UD, MD or SD (unanimous, majority or split).